# How would you draw an arrow using a loop ? (triangle rotated 90 degrees to the right)

Tags: java, nested-loops

I can print a triangle but I'd like to know how to get it to print in the form of an arrow like below and yes it is homework.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2)
     {
     for (int k = 0; k < (4 - i / 2); k++)
     {
     System.out.print(" ");
     }
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
     {
     System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.println("");
     }
```

Comment: StackOverflow users tend not to have an issue with helping out with homework, as long as you show that you're putting in effort as well. In other words, what have you tried?

Comment: well I've tried using two nested for loops when I've gotten it printed out as a normal triangle and messing around and changing the variables of the for loop but then it just turns into a big mess,,,I've read up on substrings and see how it can be a solution but I'm not too good with substrings as yet.

Comment: @midknight please provide your code and be specific what you have tried and what is troubling you, so other can help you better. break down your issue into pieces. **please try to explain your logic and thoughts as well**

Comment: I've provided the code that i can print the triangle but finding a way to get it rotated to a 90 degree position is the issue.

Comment: Don't think of it as a triangle that's rotated. Think of it as two triangles, one right-side-up, one up-side-down.

Comment: Hint: you need two for-loop (not nested).

Comment: @SimplyPanda ohhh thts a better way to view it thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{

    int mid = 10/2; //where 10 is number of lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
        if(i < mid){
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                if(j == 0 || j == i-1){
                    System.out.print("*");
                }else{
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
        } else{
            for(int j = 10 - i; j > 0; j--){
                if(j == 10-i || j == 1){
                    System.out.print("*");
                }else{
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }               
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");

    } 
}
```